# mule session values are returning null

Tags: mule

```
<flow name="authenticateqbFlow1" doc:name="authenticateqbFlow1">
     <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="qbauth" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     <set-session-variable variableName="test" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Access token Session Variable"/>
     <quickbooks:auth-user config-ref="QBAuthenticate"
            accessTokenUrl="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token"
            authorizationUrl="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin"
            callbackUrl="http://${hostname}:${port}/auth"
            requestTokenUrl="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token"
            doc:name="Authenticate user" requestTokenId="tenantId"/>
     <logger message="Session Value here is-1->#[sessionVars['test']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
<flow name="authenticateqbFlow2" doc:name="authenticateqbFlow2">
     <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="auth" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     <logger message="Session Value here is-2->#[sessionVars['test']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     <quickbooks:get-access-token config-ref="QBAuthenticate" doc:name="Quickbooks Online"/>        
     <set-payload value="Authentication: Success" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

Output from console:

```
Session Value here is-1->/qbauth

Session Value here is-2->null
```

My requirement is get the value from the URL, insert into db. I have put the value from url and set in session to insert later into db. But the problem is when I try to get the value from session I am getting null value. Note that one more inbound-endpoint involved as a call back url.
Is there anyway I can keep the values from the url and use it for insertion into db?

Comment: Is this your complete config file. I couldn't see any code to insert into DB. Also there is no connection between the two flows. How is the second flow(where the session variable is read) called from the first flow?

Comment: @user1760178, Yes it is complete flow. Inserting into db i have removed since I am unable to get session value. second flow is called with callback url: callbackUrl="http://${hostname}:${port}/auth".

Answer (score 0):

The session variable will not be passed back from the quickbooks authorization process. If it were OAuth 2, you could use the state parameter to maintain state between the request and callback.

However one solution could be to use Object Stores in mule to persist data between flows or any persistence mechanism you prefer. And key it using something unique such as the username for example. More on Object Stores here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Object+Stores
and http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-objectstore/mule/objectstore-config.html

Comment: do you know any sample application to share which is having very similar situation like above? very difficult understand mule ref docs.

Comment: Theres an example on github. https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-objectstore/blob/master/demo/src/main/app/ObjectStoreDemo.xml If you put the :store part in your first flow. And the retrieve in your second flow

Answer (score 0):

You can use Properties to set your varaible and get the value in your callback flow.

```
<set-property propertyName="test" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Property"/>
```

When you want to retrieve it use

```
#[message.inboundProperties.test]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this, it gives null value for #[message.inboundProperties.test]. since it is having a callback url which behaves like fresh request